# Is it posible to broadcast Laravel events to Socket.io without Redis?

Tags: laravel, socket.io

Good evening, programmers!

I have an issue with my program. There are several restrictions to my environment, so I cannot use Redis in it as well as Pusher. But I have to build realtime application. So, my very last alternative is socket.io.
I want to use Laravel Broadcasting System to notify my socket.io on events and after that - notify frontend part of my application with this events.

How could I do that and may be are there some packages to do this job? I will appreciate for any help!

Comment: @lewis4u it could be useful to have more details about how it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. Memcached might be something for you to look into.